# Visual Studio 2013 coverage XML file found(parsed) still Sonar 5.1.1 not able to produce code coverage

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to generate coverage file and sonarqube-5.1.1 for viewing code coverage, after analysis by sonar-runner-2.4.

The output of sonar-runner is:

```
Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor@7aa9b038 (done) | time=33447ms

Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportS nsor@72f9194d

Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report myReport.xml

Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor@72f9194d (done) | time=250ms
```

---

Even though **Sonar analysis is successful and file is parsed**, I am unable to get any code coverage in Sonar.

I'm looking this up at **localhost:9000**

Am I missing something?

NOTE: This is my sonar-project.properties file:

```
--Root project information

sonar.projectKey=myProjectKey
sonar.projectName=myProject
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

--Some properties that will be inherited by the modules

sonar.sources=myProjectParentPath
sonar.language=cs
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

--Enable the Visual Studio bootstrapper

sonar.visualstudio.enable=true

--Code Coverage

sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=myReport.xml

--Extra props

sonar.scm.provider=tfs
sonar.projectBaseDir=myProjectParentPath
```

Answer (score 0):

sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportPaths=myReport.xml should have something like myReport.coveragexml. Convert xml file to .coveragexml
It should work

Comment: It's been a long time since I reworked on this. But I vaguely remember doing that.

I'll let you know once I retry it. Thanks for your answer.